# IDE plugins for developing JMX Model MBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, eclipse-plugin, jmx

I am looking for a plugin that helps developers create JMX Model MBeans that works with either Eclipse and/or Netbeans. I am aware of the JMX Plugin for Netbeans that allows for creating of simple MBeans but looking for something more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [eclipse-jmx](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-jmx/)?  Not sure if it's advanced enough for you, but it's a plugin for Eclipse with it's own perspective, and you can display information on an MBean, set attributes, get notifications, perform operations and connect to MBean servers.

There's also the [JMX Console for Eclipse](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-314.html).  I've never used it but it has really good ratings on the Eclipse Plugin Central site.  It might be a little out of date, though...looks like it hasn't been updated since 2004.

Comment: These eclipse addins don't provide assistance in designing new mbeans, only in connecting to existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the new JBoss IDE for Eclipse might have some mbean capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think Apache Modeler may be the best fit here...

Answer (score 0):

Look into Apache common modeler, it allows you to get model mbeans from plain java class by simple registration with MbeanServer.

Look into following links:

http://liviutudor.com/2011/12/22/apache-commons-modeler-simplesample-usage/

http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/07/jmx-model-mbean.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.